# BigDecimal Exception message

Tags: java, bigdecimal

What does this means?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException
java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

But when I click on the line that would be causing the problem, there was no warning nor error. So, how do I resolve this issue? My code still runs fine, but I am clueless why my console displayed that.

**EDIT 2**

I am allowed to show this much of the codes, I hope you can understand.

```
byte[] c = new byte[13];
System.arraycopy(buf, pos, c, 0, 10);
System.arraycopy(buf, pos + 10, c, 11, 2);
c[10] = '.';
return new IsoValue(type, new BigDecimal(new String(c)), null);
```

Base on the link given by @Benjamin, there shouldn't be a problem with it.

Comment: Without code, ... I've no idea how to address this.

Comment: No need to debug the internals of JDK classes. There must be a problem in your code.

Comment: what is 'c' ? String/StringBuffer/char[]/byte[]/StringBuilder... it should represent valid number

Comment: It's a byte[] value...

Comment: Why don't you parse the original number and divide by 100?

Comment: Why do you suggest to divide the original number by 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see.

The easiest way to know what an exception is is to check the API,

First, let's open [the BigDecimal API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException
java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Means your code threw an exception, on its main execution thread. The exception was of type `NumberFormatException`, and it was thrown in BigDecimal

Let's see what the API has to say about this:

> Throws:
>   NumberFormatException - if in is not a valid representation of a BigDecimal.

(in is the input char array).

So, this exception means you're creating a BigDecimal with an invalid value. Check the code that constructs the BigDecimal. There are also a bunch of other constructors on BigDecimal, you'll find the reason depending on the overload you're using there.

Comment: Updating the question, give me awhile.

Comment: @MelvinLai Your question was "What does this mean?" , I think I've answered that.

Comment: Haha, sorry. I clicked on the wrong comment box :D supposed to be the one on top. But I can't tick this yet, gotta wait awhile more. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The docs state that a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown if the input String is not a valid representation of a `BigDecimal`... so checking the code that creates the `BigDecimal` is a good place to start.

Comment: I have updated my question, the input portion seems wrong to me. But the code shows no warning nor error, hence I kinda feel that something is wrong there...

Comment: Just because there are no compile time warnings/errors, doesn't mean that your code will run correctly at runtime.

Comment: Well, that's true. I did a breakpoint at the line that caused the exception error. The input value seems fine, but it still throws an exception. Which kind of irritates me.

Answer (score 0):

If  you  receive a value that use it convert to BigDecimal.
for example:
String receiveValue = request.getParameter("xxx");
BigDecimal  bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(receiveValue);

But problem is receiveValue is null or blank value, so that it post this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that the contents of the `byte[]` is not a number as text that it can decode.

There is nothing wrong with the code as you say,  and no reason to suspect there is as the compiler is not giving you an error.

You have a runtime error based on the input you give it, so there is a problem with the input.

Comment: I have updated my question. I feel that the input problem could be the `'.'` input. '' isn't that a `char` representation?

Answer (score 0):

You might also see some spaces in your string which can cause NumberFormatException . Trim the string .

Comment: Hi, for these types of "answers", where you attempt to give direction but are not sure about it, it's better to leave this as a comment to the question. You can see other people have commented.